# How to get PHP code into a Views Filter

Tags: 8, views

I have a text field which is extracted from photo's EXIF value; its value is similar to *2021-05-31T15:15:05*.

I want to create a view, use the filter and get the field added in.
However, I can't use PHP code for it. Instead, I have to do it manually everyday: Set *field_datetime* to *05-30* and change it to *05-31* the day after.
Is there a way to do it automatically?

I'm using Drupal 8.8.

Comment: Drupal 8 reached end of life in November 2021. Upgrade to Drupal 9.

Comment: There are two questions. 1. How to get PHP code into a Views Filter? You need a custom views filter plugin. 2. I have to do it manually everyday. Is there a way to do it automatically? Yes, you could save the View config programmatically in a cron job, this also invalidates the cache tag for the View so that it gets re-rendered.